# Visual Studio 2015 is adding projects to solution on open

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I have two different solutions on my box using Visual Studio 2015 with git. The folder structure basically looks like this:

- Source > Repos > SolutionAFolder
- Source > Repos > SolutionBFolder

Each solution folder has a solution.  Each solution has several projects.

We have been using this fine as a team for a while with no issues.  Yesterday however, when we open SolutionB, projects from SolutionA folder started automatically appearing in the root of SolutionB in the Solution Explorer.  If you view the contents of the SolutionB.sln file, it has no reference to the projects from SolutionA.  If I remove those projects from SolutionB, it marks my SolutionB.sln file as changed, but if I compare to unmodified version, there is no change.

Also, if I close and reopen Visual Studio to the SolutionB, those projects reappear one at a time (they pop in about 1 second apart from each other).  Also, if I do a hard reset on my local branch, they disappear, and then slowly reappear (similar to if I close and reopen VS).

I have other team mates that also started experiencing this same issue.  Because of that, it made me think it was something we checked into source control.  I wiped my local folders, and branched from an older version (even much older) of our solutions, and problem still comes back!

I have tried resetting VS settings, rebooting, deleting local repos, cleaning packages from .dnx, etc.

I am a bit lost where to look from here.  Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

:(  Okay, so issue ended up being that some paths got added to our global.json file.  Not sure why it never occurred to me to check there.